# using knockout with multiple views - how best to structure API

Tags: api, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a knockout application I am building that has multiple viewModels in one page.

I have been mocking data so far but I am now building the API that will run it.

My question is what do I do with complex viewModels with regards to the API.

For example I have a 'add company' page that has the following tabs:-

```
Company info (name, address, etc.)
People at company (multiple people)
Insurance Documentation (3 different types)
```

I currently have each of these as separate viewModels.

When I press save I am now confused what is the best way to do things.

If I send all 3 viewModels bundled together (add them to one master viewModel) then it becomes easy to ensure that IDs all line up but that doesn't seem very modular or a good idea and breaks the idea of being 'API Centric'.

However if I send each viewModel to a different API end-point how do I ensure that the ID's match-up correctly (people -> company) etc.

At the moment I am looking at two options:-

When press 'add new' create a blank company on the database and grab its ID -> use this to match everything up.

- OR -

When I press save send the new company up first, then when response comes back as (hopefully) ok then upload the rest of the information to their respective end-points using the now correct ID.

Both seem messy so I am wondering what is the 'accepted' best way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is how I would do it, pressing Save would send the Company model first. Then once you receive the 'OK' response with the Company id, in the callback you can add it to the other models and send them up.

Nothing messy about that, just standard asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: It just seems like I will be making lots of requests - guess that is the trade-off for trying to keep it modular! I will mark as correct if dont get any better answers - thanks - guess it was just 'analysis paralysis!!' :-D

Comment: It's not a bad thing to make lots of little requests to APIs, it is indeed what keeps it modular. You can then reuse the exact same documentation API call somewhere else, for example.